# Good Practice - Passing instance and call methods on instance

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to bounce something off you guys.

In my Mobile App, I have a lot of Activity and Fragment classes and many of them contain a method or two with code for uploading images to a WebAPI 2.0 web service etc. etc. Sorry, just for info.

Now, I thought about creating a new class (e.g. ServiceController) and then move all the Service Calls to this new class. The problem is, each one for the methods contain code for displaying a ProgressBar and hiding a ProgressBar, and let the activity continue to a next one, etc. etc.

Now, is it good practice to pass an instance of the Activity that is calling the method in the ServiceController to the method in the ServiceController and then for instance do this:

public static void uploadImages(Activity activity) {
    new BaseAsyncTask() { 
        ...
        ...
        activity.hideProgressBar();
        ...
}

PS: Specifically the "activity.hideProgressBar();" above.

Thanks and have fun,
Pieter

Comment: Did you ever hear of Model-View-Presenter, or some other pattern? If you don't mix ui with business logic you can reuse more code and have cleaner interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of decoupling between the classes , First of all service  calls shouldn't be in the activity

**first solution** 
 1) Create one interface which contains onsuccess , onfailure abstract methods , and the parameters for that methods will be respective data model class types
2) The above interface should be implemented by activity which is dependent of data from server .In these implementation the showing and hiding progress bar , populating UI with data takes place
3)As you said ,Service Controller Instance will be created , while creating the instance of Service controller we have pass the reference of the interface . these interface is used for communication between service controller and activity.

**second solution**

Use Event Bus For Communicating between service controller and Activity 
[OTTO EVENT BUS](http://square.github.io/otto/) i will prefer these .

Let me know if you have any queries , I Hope these will solve your problem.

**third solution**

use MVP Pattern Refer [MVP Architecture Tutorial](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/) Best solution of all